# What are the problems in 3-way Message passing Reliable IPC protocol?

Tags: operating-system, distributed-system, message-passing

[image: 3-way Message passing reliable IPC Protocol diagram]

Here, at the end of this page. last paragraph , 
They mentioned some problems that occurs in This protocol. 
i am unable to understand what are these problems. ?
for example. He told. "If a request processing long time"
I am unable to understand this statement.  Where is the request which processing taking long time, on client ? or on server ? 
Or i am unable to understand where is the Clock(time) ? is it on Client side or Server Side? because here mentioned in the end of 2 point.  "if the reply is not received within the time period , the kernel of the client machine re-transmits the request message."

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

- The client sends a message. If it doesn't get a reply from the server within - say - 1 minute it will transmit the message again.
- When the server receives a message, it only sends a reply *after* having generated a full response to the message that the client sent.

No suppose you, as client, send a message to the server. The server receives your message, and starts processing it. At this time, you, the client, have no idea of whether the server got the message or not. Assume you send a complicated task to the server, which takes it 1 minute and 5 seconds to complete. After 1 minute (ignoring transmission times), the server is still busy doing your work, but you as the client don't know of any of this and send your message again.

Now, depending on the actual protocol implementation, there are a few potential issues:

- It's possible that by sending the message again, you increase some sequence count and are therefore unable to receive the reply to the original message afterwards.
- It's possible that the server isn't able to determine whether a message that arrives is the first message or a message that had to be send again. So it could be doing work that it already did, leading either to needless processing or in the worst case to (business) logic errors.

Additionally, by sending both the message and the reply possibly needless more than once, you increase the amount of total data transmitted, without gaining anything from it.

To "solve" this, you could increase the waiting time before the client sends its message again. This will "fix" the issue with long running tasks on the server, but will also hurt in case the message *actually got lost* on the way, because you're waiting longer to even send a new message.

The "real" solution here is to have the server acknowledge as soon as it receives a message from the client, just as saying "i got your message, i'll send the reply soon!" before even starting to actually process the message.